# Which is RX and TX pin of the HM-10 module?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, wireless

i recently bought hm-10[image: Back view of HM-10 BLE module] ble module which works using cc2541 ti SOC but problem is there are many ports the the bluetooth module but the seller has not mentioned which is rx and tx pins so...
I wanted to connnect it with Arduino uno and use AT commands but now i am stuck can anyone in this community help me finding which pin is Tx and Rx and the data sheet of the module is difficult to find on the net .....[image: Front view of module]

Comment: http://www.electrodragon.com/w/EY-08 might help

Comment: Seems like the link is broken. Here is another https://github.com/nickswalker/ble-dev-kit/wiki/HM-10-Pinout

Answer (score 1):

That's not an HM-10 but an EY-08. It's the same chip, but it's been provided in a different footprint (and maybe with different firmware installed).

Pin P03 is TX and pin P02 is RX.

The AT command set, pinouts, and examples for wiring it are detailed [here](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/EY-08) (Thanks to Mikael Patel for finding that link).